# Ползет картинка при масштабирования карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть задача, разместить на карте Яндекс зону охвата передатчика. 
Зона охвата - это картинка, которую надо растянуть на некоторую территорию.

Сделано так:
Картинка располагается как заполнитель в объекте Rectangle. Объект Rectagle имеет гео-координаты, что заставляет картинку расплываться на нужную территорию.

Всё хорошо, работает.

Но, как недавно обнаружилось, при масштабировании (приближении) наступает момент, когда картинка зоны охвата ломается.

Код примера для локального запуска прилагается здесь https://cloud.mail.ru/public/EsK4/V4VLVjCew

Если запустить пример, то на 1 час от Новохоперска увидим населенный пункт Васильевка. Пробуем увеличивать карту так, чтобы Васильевка была по центру. Розовое пятно сползает. На Васильевку переползает кусок пятна, который в нормальном виде находится примерно на 11 часов, на одной горизонтали с Васильевкой

Обводка объекта Rectagle на этом примере показана намеренно, чтобы было понятно, в каких пределах надо растягивать картинку.

Вопрос - что я делаю не так?
Или это это движок так делает? 
Может есть другие способы, добиться такого же результата другими средствами Yandex Maps?

Спасибо!

Comment: Кажется, исправлено в версии 2.1.73

Answer (score 1):

Передал вашу проблему разработчикам. Пока можно использовать другую версию апи - 2.1.68 .

Comment: Да, версия 2.1.68 отрабатывает нормально. Переехал на неё. Спасибо!